# Open boostrap modal from another boostrap modal make body permanently got padding right

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I have 2 bootstrap modal in the same page: `#modal1` and `#modal2`. `#modal2` can be toggled by clicking the **Show** button on  `#modal1`.

Here is my javascript code :

```
$('#modal1 .show-btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#modal2').modal('show');
});
```

The problem is that when `#modal2` is opened and closed, the CSS rule `padding-right: 16px;` is added to the body tag permanently.

Is there any way to prevent that `padding-right` when `#modal2` is toggled?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete `.fade` class from your modal if you don't need an animation, I heard that this could help. Or you could simply use some CSS3 magic and prevent adding `padding-right` to your `body` element completely like this:

```
body { padding-right: 0 !important }
```

Or something like this to prevent adding a `padding-right` when your model is open:

```
.modal-open {
   padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```